# JAVA RESTEasy Service HTTP Status 404

Tags: resteasy, java

I am new in JAVA RESTEasy Service and I followed the below URL for create JAVA RESTEasy Service

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/09/tutorial-54-getting-started-with-resteasy-using-eclipse/

But I am getting the below Error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /test/dateservice/getdate

type Status report

message /test/dateservice/getdate

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
```

web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

web service class code

```
package test_pack;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("dateservice")
public class todService
{
    @GET
    @Path("getdate")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getDate() 
    {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Inside getDate");
        String date = null;
        Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        date = currentDate.toString();
        System.out.println("return>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+Response.status(200).entity(date).build());
        return Response.status(200).entity(date).build();
    }
}
```

I am using the below jar file

[image]

I run this using below URL

http://localhost:8080/test/dateservice/getdate

What am I missing?

Comment: @OpenSourceEnthu you means that, <url-pattern></url-pattern> nothing write between them?

Comment: I did exactly mention in http://karanbalkar.com/2013/09/tutorial-54-getting-started-with-resteasy-using-eclipse/, It worked for me...I am using tomcat 8, jaxrs-api-3.0.11.Final.jar,resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar, scannotation-1.0.3.jar, javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar. My Url: http://localhost:8080/RestEasyServices/dateservice/getdate, o/p: Mon May 16 13:06:35 IST 2016,  I have not change port of Tomcat server

Comment: url should be: http://localhost:8080/<project_name>/dateservice/getdate, and not display name as mention in web.xml